# Why does SQLAlchemy 1.1 cause core dump committing multiple dirty records outside of function where mutation happens?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

## Setup

Suppose I have a table with two fields: a string primary key and a boolean flag. I want to query multiple rows and then update the flag across all of them, then commit my changes.

## SQLAlchemy 1.0

In SQLAlchemy 1.0, the following worked:

```
sm = sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=True,
    expire_on_commit=True,
    bind=engine,  # MySQL engine
)
session_factory = scoped_session(sm)

def modify_records(session, flag=False):
    records = session.query(TestSQLTable).all()
    for r in records:
        r.flag = flag

session = session_factory()
modify_records(session)
session.commit()
```

## SQLAlchemy 1.1

Now, this does *not* work and causes a core dump. I am unable to tell what change was made in 1.1 that causes this different behavior when reading the ["What's New in SQLAlchemy 1.1?"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_11.html) guide.

If I do this in a Jupyter notebook, for instance, the kernel just crashes on commit without any error.

However, this **does** work for just a single row:

```
def modify_record(session, flag=False):
    record = session.query(TestSQLTable).first()
    record.flag = flag
```

### Ways I have gotten this to work

#### Add an explicit return

```
def modify_records(session, flag=False):
    records = session.query(TestSQLTable).all()
    for r in records:
        r.flag = flag
    return records  # ADD THIS!
```

#### Flush after each mutation

```
def modify_records(session, flag=False):
    records = session.query(TestSQLTable).all()
    for r in records:
        r.flag = flag
        session.flush()  # ADD THIS!
```

#### Restructure code so that the commit happens inside `modify_records`

This works, but is not the way the application is currently built and would thus require a major refactor (b/c commit happens via a decorator).

## Main question

Why does this happen exactly for multiple records and why did this work in 1.0 but does not in 1.1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This'd seem like it belongs to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sqlalchemy) or the [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues) so that the devs can better address it. If you do post it, include exact versions of all involved libraries (your DB-API driver included), full traceback information and your models.

Comment: A quick test with SQLAlchemy 1.1.13, PyMySQL 0.7.11, and MySQL server 5.7.18 in a single thread using a test model with a boolean column flag I was not able to reproduce. Since adding a single return "fixes" your issue, this would seem to be somewhat timing related. Does your real code include multiple threads operating concurrently?

Comment: And more importantly: does your real code use `multiprocessing` to split work to multiple processes?

Comment: Alright... I was able to track this down to a cPython problem in Python 3.6.0.  This reproes with SQLite as well. When moving to Python 3.6.2, this goes away.

This fixed the culprit: https://github.com/serhiy-storchaka/cpython/commit/5aafff22a20715d276a23d30b7335bbecbc31754